# $x^{x+y} =y^{n} $ AND $y^{x+y} =x^{2n}\cdot{ y^{n}}.$

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations, quadratics

Please help solve the system of equations. 
$$x^{x+y} =y^n$$
$$y^{x+y} =x^{2n}\cdot y^{n} $$
Where it is given that$ n=0$.
I tried to solve it by taking log both sides but couldn't arrive at any result. 
My attempt :(

Taking log both sides 
$$ (x+y) \log x = n\cdot \log y$$
And then I divided both the equations to get
$${(\frac{x} {y}) } ^{x+y} =\frac{1} {x^{2 n}} $$
Taking log both sides 
$$ (x+y)( \log x-\log y)= \frac{-\log x} {2n}$$
But I can't find a way to proceed from here. Please help

Comment: If it is given that $n = 0$, it is trivial to solve. $y^0 = 1$ and $x^{0}y^{0} = 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:** $$x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8n}}{2},~~n>0, ~~\mbox{and}~~ y=x^2.$$
**Proof:**

$$x^{x+y}=y^n~~~~(1),~~~~ y^{x+y}=x^{2n}y^n~~~~(2)$$
Here $x,y,n>0$,
multiply (1) and (2) to get 
$$(xy)^{x+y}=(xy)^{2n} \Rightarrow x+y=2n~~~~(3).$$
Use (3) in (1) to get
$$x^2=y~~~(4)$$
From (3) and (4), we get
$$x^2+x-2n=0 \Rightarrow x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8n}}{2},~~n>0$$

Comment: Don't forget $x = y = 1$. $x = y = 1$ is a solution whether $n > 0$ or $n < 0$. In fact it is the only solution if $n < 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$(x+y)\log x = n\log y$ and $(x+y)\log y = 2n\log x + n\log y$

Dividing the first equation by the second,

$$\frac{\log x}{\log y}=\frac{\log y}{2\log x+\log y}$$

Putting $\frac{\log x}{\log y}=t$, we have $t=\frac{1}{2t+1}$ or $(2t-1)(t+1)=0$.

Substituting $x=y^t$ and $x+y=\frac nt$, it should be easily solvable from here.